# Simple MS SQL count question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL

```
DECLARE @url varchar(100)
SET @url = 'http://mysite.com/%'

SELECT
[UserSessionSequenceID]
      ,[SiteID]
      ,[Referer]
      ,[Timestamp]
,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY [Referer] ORDER BY referer DESC) AS sort 
  FROM [tblSequence]
WHERE [Referer] IS NOT NULL AND [Referer] NOT LIKE @url AND siteID = 15
```

Want to count unique referer - problem is that this SQL returns ALL matches and count those one by one. 
I only want the count for each unique referer (and still exsluding the @url with like).

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
      [Referer], Count([Referer]) as RefCount
  FROM [tblSequence]
WHERE [Referer] IS NOT NULL AND [Referer] NOT LIKE @url AND siteID = 15
GROUP BY [Referer]
```

Putting Order back in (should that really be required) depends on your exact requirements.

Comment: Looks good - what if I want to add the [timestamp] in the overall where clause?
AND ([Timestamp] > DATEADD(dd, -1, (LEFT(GETDATE(),12))))

Comment: This was my first thought, but then I realise OP wants unique referer count and unaggregated row data in one call. Sorry everyone for my previous typo...

Comment: Seo20 - please indicate whether you're looking for an answer like gbn has indicated, or aggregation like I'm doing. I suspect gbn's method is more what you want. But what's holding you back from just adding the WHERE statement you just gave in your comment? (In either solution)

Answer (score 3):

Use [DENSE_RANK not ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) if you require row data instead of an aggregate

Comment: Change "ROW_NUMBER()" to "DENSE_RANK()" in the query you posted

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @url varchar(100)
 SET @url = 'http://example.com/%'

  SELECT
  distinct [UserSessionSequenceID]
  ,[SiteID]
  ,[Referer]
  ,[Timestamp]
 ,count(*) over (PARTITION BY [Referer] ORDER BY referer DESC) AS sort 
  FROM [tblSequence]
  WHERE [Referer] IS NOT NULL AND [Referer] NOT LIKE @url AND siteID = 15
```